# OSGi - How to add JVM parameter with FUSE ESB?

Tags: java, jvm, osgi, fuseesb

In command line, I can run a java file like:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -jar floodlight.jar
```

But in OSGi container like FUSE ESB, I cannot add such

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml
```

How can I do the same thing when use osgi container?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add all system properties to the `etc/system.properties` file.
So in your case you might try to append:

`logback.configurationFile=logback.xml`

or if this is not working and you have placed the file in the etc directory:

`logback.configurationFile=${karaf.home}/etc/logback.xml`

Note that this is not a `*.cfg` file and therefore is not covered by the config admin and might require a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Fuse ESB have Pax Logging service which supports logback API. You could specify your logback configuration file location in the Pax Logging configuration file. Just add `org.ops4j.pax.logging.logback.config.file=<PATH_TO_LOGBACK_FILE>/logback.xml` to the `etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` file.

Comment: Hi I did exactly what you said. Add: org.ops4j.pax.logging.logback.config.file=/home/li/Documents/Java/logback.xml to /opt/FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg. When I start the bundle it still output the log on screen.

Comment: How your logback config looks like?